# Ansible-vault inline encrypted string throws error

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm having trouble with inline encrypted strings in Ansible/Ansible-vault.

I'm storing the Ansible Vault password in a file and have a local config file that declares it:

```
[defaults]
vault_password_file = ./my_vault_pass
```

As I already have a vault_password_file defined, I create my encrypted variable with the following command:

`ansible-vault encrypt_string --stdin-name 'username'`

When prompted, I enter the value I want encrypted and CTRL-D twice without pressing enter.  I then take the output of that command and replace the variable definition with it.

My tasks/main.yml file ends up like this [redacted]

```yaml
---
- name: Clone the template
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: 1.2.3.4
    username: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          63353665383934386565306639633734366666303465306364323761323938383433643133313933
          3939356663626465303465646265653731626463386261610a306361343436613030336639303533
          64613337326332353933313931303537653833623863343435623730316266643636373831363937
          6231643937376665620a326465343239643237366465353965376532336365346631653466623038
          35636135303233623733306632333833663535646230393335303261633535353636
    password: 'my_password'
    validate_certs: False
    name: testvm_2
    template: 'template-name'
    datacenter: DC1
    folder: /Test
    state: poweredon
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
```

However, with the `username:` change being the only change, I now get an error:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [common : Clone the template] *******************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to pass options to module, they must be JSON serializable: Object of type AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode is not JSON serializable"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution to my own question:

It doesn't seem possible in Ansible to encrypt module variables.  A workaround to this is to indirect the variable to a vars.yml file using the Jinja syntax described in [Tips & Tricks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#keep-vaulted-variables-safely-visible).

i.e.

tasks.yml

```
    password: '{{ vault_password }}'
```

And then in vars.yml (I used vars/main.yml as I'm using the [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html) for directory layout.

```
vault_password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          30373438353463646433363433616631616434616237636432653530353330636236666332363661
          6565323338643139623737646431333332383432613962640a636537306139646539303762646166
          61363435643137363738656235613330663131613333656538323035666261336334383138663965
          6365356130346537300a363961623261653030363433353737386666306131336631343633396262
          6565
```

Comment: `It doesn't seem possible in Ansible to encrypt module variables` <= I would have a lot of work to do in a very short time if this was true and a lot of our old playbooks would fail. This cannot be be source of your problem, there is someging you have missed. Ansible does a lot of magic when re-interpreting variables in chain like you did in your second try. I would bet this is what "fixed" the issue. Meanwhile, having encrypted vars in your inventory or seperate files is actually a good practice.

Comment: @Zeitounator Interesting, I was closing my own issue with the answer after chatting on  the #ansible Freenode channle.  As the workaround seemed to be effective I haven't pursued this further but I'll keep it in mind, thanks.